# Yii2. How to avoid "incorrect code" while using Captcha + Ajax?

Tags: ajax, yii2, captcha

I'm trying to solve this great issue, but cannot find pretty and simple solution.
Captcha doesn't work properly when ajax validation is enabled.
There is always "Incorrect captcha code".

view.php:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
            'id' => 'form-signup',
            'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
        ]); ?>
```

action:

```
public function actionSignup()
{
    $model = new SignupForm();

    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

        Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
        return ActiveForm::validate($model);
    }

    if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

        if ($user = $model->signup()) {

            if (Yii::$app->getUser()->login($user)) {
                return $this->goHome();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the AJAX validation generates a new code in the background (since it's a new request), creating this problem were you are always validating against the wrong code.

If you 100% need to use AJAX validation, you must setup a captcha action in your controller. This way, the captcha always gets validated against the same code across the same session. To do this, you need to:

1. Add the `captcha` action in the controller to create the images:

```php
use yii\captcha\CaptchaAction;

public function actions()
{
    return [
        // other actions...
        'captcha' => [
            'class' => CaptchaAction::class,
        ],
    ];
}
```

2. Define `captchaAction` in your model rules pointing to the controller-action you created before:

```php
function rules()
{
    return [
        // other rules...
        ['verificationCode', 'captcha', 'captchaAction' => 'your-controller/captcha'],
    ];
}
```

3. Make the widget in the view use the captcha action instead of the default one:

```php
<?php echo $form->field($model, 'verificationCode')->widget(Captcha::className(), [
    'captchaAction' => 'your-controller/captcha'
]) ?>
```

More info on:

1. Captcha Action (controller): https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-captcha-captchaaction
2. Captcha Validator (model): https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-captcha-captchavalidator
3. Captcha Widget (view): https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-captcha-captcha

Comment: I have tried it earlier, but it doesn't work. All fields of the form are validated successfully, but after clicking on submit button - code is incorrect.

Comment: You might need to also disable client validation in your form options